# jquery alert after validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, alert

I m not sure what i m doing wrong other than I m a beginner in jquery. i need to send these values to server through ajax for further dmas calculation after that but validation is not working

```js
<script>
    $('#button').click( function() {
        $("#form").validate({
            rules: {
                input_one: {
                    required: true,
                    number: true
                },
                input_two: {
                    required: true,
                    number: true
                }
            },
            messages: {
                input_one: {
                    required: "1stinput is empty",
                    number: "invalid entry in 1st input"
                },
                input_two: {
                    required: "2nd input is empty",
                    number: "invalid entry in 2nd input"
                }
                
            },

            errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
                alert(error.text());
            },

        }).form();

    });

</script>
```

```html
<form id="form" name="form" method="post" action="">
    Input one <input id="input_one" name="input_one" class="required" type="text" /><br><br>
    Input Two <input id="input_one" name="input_one" class="required" type="text" /><br><br>

    <button class="button" id="plus"> Plus </button>
    <button class="button" id="sub"> Minus</button>
    <button class="button" id="mul"> Multiply </button>
    <button class="button" id="div"> Divide </button><br><br><br> RESULT:
    <p id="result"></p>

</form>
```

Comment: `button` is a class `.button` instead of `#button`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have duplicate names in your code. Make second input name attribute as **'input_two'**.
Also use **submitHandler** method in jQuery validate. here you will get form once validation pass for all input fields. Remove alert from **errorPlacement** function as it is not good practice of using alert in JS code try to use **console.log** statement.

Also remove button click event. No need of click handler here because by default your buttons will act as submit in the form.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset='utf-8'>
    <meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=edge'>
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1'>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery-validation@1.19.3/dist/jquery.validate.js">  </script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#form").validate({
                    rules: {
                        input_one: {
                            required: true,
                            number: true
                        },
                        input_two: {
                            required: true,
                            number: true
                        }
                    },
                    messages: {
                        input_one: {
                            required: "1stinput is empty",
                            number: "invalid entry in 1st input"
                        },
                        input_two: {
                            required: "2nd input is empty",
                            number: "invalid entry in 2nd input"
                        }

                    },

                    errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
                        console.log(error)
                    },
                    submitHandler: function (form) {
                        console.log('Form Submitted');
                        // It is optional submit form or use AJAX snippet here to make AJAX call
                      //  form.submit();
                    }

                });

            // $('.button').click(function () {
               
            // });

        });

    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <form id="form" name="form" method="post" action="">
        Input one <input id="input_one" name="input_one" class="required" type="text" /><br><br>
        Input Two <input id="input_one" name="input_two" class="required" type="text" /><br><br>

        <button class="button" id="plus" type="submit"> Plus </button>
        <button class="button" id="sub" > Minus</button>
        <button class="button" id="mul"> Multiply </button>
        <button class="button" id="div"> Divide </button><br><br><br> RESULT:
        <p id="result"></p>

    </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: it worked quiet well, just that alert is required by enquirer and it was constantly alerting after the error. used : '  error.insertAfter(element); ' for that. 
btw no need for those messages also after validation plugin